# Matching variables to an array using user input in Python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, matching

I can't figure out why the steps aren't changing to go through the loop and check each step.

```
# MichiganCities.py - This program prints a message for invalid cities in 
Michigan.  
# Input:  Interactive
# Output:  Error message or nothing
# Initialized list of cities
citiesInMichigan = ["Acme", "Albion", "Detroit", "Watervliet", "Coloma", 
"Saginaw", "Richland", "Glenn", "Midland", "Brooklyn"] 
inCity = "userinput"
step = 0
size = 10
while step < size:
    inCity = input("Enter name of city: ")  # Get user input
    print (inCity)
    if inCity == citiesInMichigan[step]: # If the city is found, print "City found."
        print ("City found.")
        step = step +1
    else:
        print ("Not a city in Michigan.") # Otherwise, "Not a city in 
Michigan" 
message should be printed.
```

Comment: Why no just do `if inCity in citiesInMichigan`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
citiesInMichigan = ["Acme", "Albion", "Detroit", "Watervliet", "Coloma", 
"Saginaw", "Richland", "Glenn", "Midland", "Brooklyn"] 
inCity = "userinput"
step = 0
size = 10
while step < size:
    inCity = input("Enter name of city: ")  # Get user input
    print (inCity)
    if inCity in citiesInMichigan: # If the city is found, print "City found."
        print ("City found.")
        step = step +1
    else:
        print ("Not a city in Michigan.") # Otherwise, "Not a city in  Michigan" message should be printed.
```

Hi! Please try this. Hope it works